# How to edit sudoers file in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

I accidentally changed the mode of the file /etc/sudoers and added a 
line to the file.

Now every time I want to "sudo", I got a  error message like "parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 21"

I can't login as a root also now. How can I solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
pkexec visudo
```

Comment: polkit doesn't help when you don't have a GUI.